# How to save and display log information simultaneously by using Ruby command

Tags: ruby, logging

I have tried `ruby test.rb > Result.txt`

However, printf information only saves in result.txt but it does not show in Ruby console.

Any Ruby command could save and display log information simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on unix:

```
ruby test.rb | tee Result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I am using Windows. OK, I will try to install 'tee' in my OS. Thank you